# How to store only available columns in DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, excel, datagridview

i have excel file with several columns and i was able import it to my DataGridView in C# Win Forms so user can see and edit the data.. 
the problem is: how to store the data in the DataGridView to the sql server which stores only available Column on the Database..
this is the quick illustration..

[image: database]

[image: excel]

this my current  codes..

```
    private void buttonImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialogExcel.FileName != "Excel File")
        {
            try
            {
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
                System.Data.DataSet DtSet;
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter MyCommand;
                MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='"
                + openFileDialogExcel.FileName + "';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");
                MyCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Data$]", MyConnection);
                MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Student");
                DtSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
                MyCommand.Fill(DtSet);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables[0];

                MyConnection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception Fail)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(Fail.ToString());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Browse 1st");
        }
    }
```

And i have 1 button for saving the data exclude "Gender" Columns..

```
private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    -----BLANK :(

}
```

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just INSERT these data on the server the most optimum way would be to use Bulk operation...

```
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(YourConnectionString))
        {
            cn.Open();
            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(cn))
            {
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Student";

                try
                {
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("StudentID", "StudentID");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Address", "Address");

                    // Bulk write on the server
                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(DtSet.Tables[0]);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }

        }
```